# I want to dynamic change dialog's list item's textcolor. But list.getChildAt() confused me very much! Can you help me?

Tags: android

I got that it seems the list.getchildAt() method return not null only when the list has shown once. If the list has not shown before, I call List.getChildAt() will return null. How can I do it, I want before the dialog's list shown before to change the list item's textcolor?

Comment: What?!?! Can you please explain more precisely what you're trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

If your background is not data-sensible, you can style your list applying a custom theme to it: set the items' background, selector, etc.

If you need your list items to have different background based on the data they display, you should create your own `ListView`, and put it inside a `Dialog`.
In your `ListView` implementation you override the `ListAdapter`'s `getView` method, and set the proper background for the current item.